# Flutter - Background appears between widgets when using bottom rounded borders, how to hide or connect widget borders?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to make a screen where all bottom border (except the last one at bottom) should have a rounded bottom border, left and right.

I'm able to create the rounded borders, but, how can I hide the background color ou round top borders and connect it to the previous widget?

As you can see in image below, I have the rounded borders but the background color (green) appears between blue and red. How can I hide it?

How can I achieve that borders connection?

[image: Rounded borders layout]

**Code**

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: <Widget>[
            ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(15)),
              child: Container(
                height: 250.0,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    bottom: 6.0), //Same as `blurRadius` i guess
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(15)),
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      offset: Offset(0.0, 1.0), //(x,y)
                      blurRadius: 6.0,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(15)),
              child: Container(
                height: 300.0,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    bottom: 6.0), //Same as `blurRadius` i guess
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(15)),
                  color: Colors.red,
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      offset: Offset(0.0, 1.0), //(x,y)
                      blurRadius: 6.0,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),            
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've wrapped the first ClipRRect inside a Container with the color (background) of the next ClipRRec, by this I achieve the effect I wanted. I'm not sure if it's the right way

```
Container(
         color: Colors.red,
         child: ClipRRect(
             borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
             bottomLeft: Radius.circular(15),
             bottomRight: Radius.circular(15)),
             child: Container(
                  height: 250.0,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      bottom: 6.0), //Same as `blurRadius` i guess
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(15)),
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        offset: Offset(0.0, 1.0), //(x,y)
                        blurRadius: 6.0,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

**Result**

[image: Rounded Borders Result]